# How can I control row height and cell padding in yii2 detailView?

Tags: html, css, yii2

I want to decrease the size of a detail view. I was able to decrease font-size through css, but can not decrease row size or padding of the generated table.

```
    <div class="col-md-3">
            <?= DetailView::widget([
                'model' => $model,
                'attributes' => [
                    'id',
                    'jmn',
                    'pri',
                    'rci',
                    'adr',
                    'tel',
                    'eml',
                ],
            ]) ?>
    </div>
```

css

```
.detail-view {
    font-size: 10px;  -> this works
}
td {
    padding: 0px;  -> this doesnt do anything
    margin: 0px; -> this doesnt do anything
    background:green; -> this works (a test :-)
}
tr { line-height: 30px; } -> this doesnt do anything
```

Answer (score 0):

Add style in the interessed field e.g.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
        <?= DetailView::widget([
            'model' => $model,
            'attributes' => [
                 'id',
                 'jmn',
                 ....
                 [
                    'attribute' => 'attribute_name',
                    ....
                    'options' => ['style' => 'width:90px;'],
                    .....
                 ],
          ....
        ]) ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this however produced errors.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to put `!important` at the end of last css line:

```
td { padding:0px !important; height: 5px !important; }
```

Also it's better to be more specific in css selector. So something like this is better:

```
#your-table-id tr { line-height: 30px !important; }
```

If did not work, try to add css style inside the widget in this way:

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
            'model' => $model,
            'attributes' => [
                 [                      
                   'label' => 'ID',
                   'value' => $model->id,
                   'options' => ['style' => ' line-height: 30px']
                 ],
               ...
            ],
        ]) ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped me to find the solution - the problem was that padding was set in bootstrap.css, which did not get overridden with td {padding : 0px}. I had to add td {padding : 0px !important;} to override this.